# Future time series forecasting using LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, lstm, sklearn-pandas

I have written LSTM sequential code for forecasting time series as follows

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, no_input)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=20, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

Code works well with tested data. Now my question is, for example, If I want to forecast next 10K data, how can I do this? Where Just giving `number of data to be forecasted`, generates future values?

Comment: you can predict data by appending the predicted result in chain

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more with example if possible?

Comment: [link] (https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-step-time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-networks-python/) hope this will clear your question.